# abstracting Promises, how to pass arguments to functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to JS and practicing with Promises.

I have the following structure, which works:

```
Database.load('menus')
 .then((value) => {return JSON.parse(value)})
 .then((parsed) => {return parsed['Menu'].map(Menu.create)})
 .then(console.log)
 .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

I would like to make it a reusable function and abstract away the literals, I've tried:

```
parse = (value) => {return JSON.parse(value)}
createObject = (parsed) => {return parsed[key].map(`${key}`.create)}

convert = (name, key) => {
  Database.load(name)
  .then(parse)
  .then(createObject)
  .then(console.log)
}
convert('menus', 'Menu')
```

But this is returning:

```
(node:51848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: key is not defined
```

Comment: You're not passing `key` into `createObject` where it's expected.

Comment: @Andy, I've tried to pass it, as `createObject = (parsed, key) => {return parsed[key].map(`${key}`.create)}` but then it's returning `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: where do you think *createObject = (parsed) => {return parsed[key].map(\`${key}\`.create)}* will get `key` from?

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right. Mistake when writing the question, I've corrected it.

Comment: OK, so ... the important question remains, where do you suppose `createObject` would get `key` from?

Comment: I've tried to add the key in the argument, as in the previous comment, but then I would get undefined for the 'parsed' value. So it only takes either `key` or `parsed`. When promises only return one value, how could I pass two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is not visible in the required context.

```
parse = (value) => {
  return JSON.parse(value)
}
createObject = (key) => { (parsed) => {
  return parsed[key].map(`${key}`.create)
}};

convert = (name, key) => {
  Database.load(name)
    .then(parse)
    .then(createObject(key))
    .then(console.log)
}
convert('menus', 'Menu')
```

Comment: `return (parsed)` is blocking `key` from being passed.

Comment: sorry, I didn't test the code, I just described the concept

Answer (score 2):

@bluehipy's answer the way to go, though I'd write `creatObject` like

```
const createObject = key => parsed => parsed[key].map(`${key}`.create);
```

An alternative, which may be more easy to understand, and doesn't require a function returning a function - not that there's anything wrong with that, I'd do it like the above, but it can do your head in if you're relatively new to JS

```
const parse = value => JSON.parse(value);

const convert = (name, key) => {
    const createObject = parsed => parsed[key].map(`${key}`.create);

    return Database.load(name)
    .then(parse)
    .then(createObject)
    .then(console.log);
};
```